# Github Actions: create a pull request after formatting code with psf/black

Tags: python, github-actions

In my github formatting workflow I have the following step:

```
- name: Format with black
      uses: psf/black@stable
      id: action_black
      with:
        options: "--verbose"
        src: "./src"
```

after which I have copied from another action template a step which should open a pull request if black did format any of its target files:

```
- name: Create Pull Request
      if: steps.action_black.outputs.is_formatted == 'true'
      uses: peter-evans/create-pull-request@v3
      with:
        token: ${{ secrets.GITHUB_TOKEN }}
        title: "Format Python code with psf/black push"
        commit-message: ":art: Format Python code with psf/black"
        body: |
          There appear to be some python formatting errors in ${{ github.sha }}. This pull request
          uses the [psf/black](https://github.com/psf/black) formatter to fix these issues.
        base: ${{ github.head_ref }} # Creates pull request onto pull request or commit branch
        branch: actions/black
```

but the if line, which I do not fully understand, is wrong and therefore the rest of this step is skipped.

Can anyone please help me understand how to tie the official **psf/black** action to **peter-evans/create-pull-request@v3** in such a way that the pull request is activated **ONLY** if any file has been changed/formatted? Thanks.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`is_formatted` is not part of psf's black github action according to this: https://github.com/rickstaa/action-black

readme says:

> IMPORTANT: The official psf/black action has been released! Since psf/black has been released, the action in this repository is not trivial anymore. Therefore, you are advised to use the official black action. Some features in this action are not in the official action. The differences between the two actions are documented in #10. Please open a pull request if you think features are missing.

And the linked issue says that `is_formatted` is not supported.

Maybe switch the action rickstaa's action or see add a second step after psf/black that checks if the git checkout is dirty and set a variable accordingly that you can then check in the create-pull-request step ?

Comment: Thank you so much @rasjani. Early learner here :) Well first of all I had to wrangle the repo's Actions settings granting read/write and pull requests from the bot. Hope this has no unintended security consequences. The rest of your suggestion I need to study a bit more to understand. As you guessed I only want to generate a pull request if any of the files have been formatted or the pull would be issued even on a 100% formatted codebase :(

Comment: your example will most likely work if you just switch the `uses: psf/black@stable`  line to point to rickstaa's `uses: rickstaa/action-black@v1`

Comment: rickstaa/action-black specifically encourages NOT using it and use the official action instead. I did try the psf/black action without the if line and it seems to work well, meaning it will not create a pull request if nothing has been changed.